# How to record a three seconds of still image with filter animation filtered by GPUImage

Tags: ios, gpuimage, video-recording

I have a still image attached with a GPUImage filter, some parameters of which are animating, giving the static image a dynamic look. Now I want to record the dynamic animation down to a 3 seconds m4v file.

This is how I have tried,

```
- (IBAction)onBtnSaveAnim:(id)sender {
//save animation for 3 seconds
NSString *pathToMovie = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:ExportMovieFile];
unlink([pathToMovie UTF8String]);
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie];
GPUImageMovieWriter *movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:movieURL size:CGSizeMake(720, 1280)];
self.movieWriter = movieWriter;
movieWriter.shouldPassthroughAudio = YES;
[self.stillImageFilter addTarget:movieWriter];
self.stillImageSource.audioEncodingTarget = movieWriter;

[movieWriter startRecording];

[GCDQueue executeInMainQueue:^{
    [self.stillImageFilter removeTarget:movieWriter];
    [movieWriter finishRecording];

    [[KKAssetManager si] syncSaveVideoURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:pathToMovie]];

}afterDelaySecs:3];}
```

It did not work as expected, so how could I fix the code?